# About frattini subalgebra

Tags: lie-algebras

why if $C$ is a subalgebra of $A$ and $B$ is an ideal of $A$ contained in $F(C)$, then $B$ is contained in $F(A)$?

$F(A)$ is Frattini subalgebra of $A$. Can I use this for Leibniz algebras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that B is not contained in F(A). Then there is a maximal subalgebra M of A such that A = B + M. But now C = B + M \cap C = F(C) + M \cap C = M \cap C. It follows that C is contained in M, whence B is contained in M, a contradiction.

Comment: :How should I use the B ideal?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What do you want to use it for?

Comment: :can B is subalgebra not ideal?

Comment: No, the proof doesn't work then, as B + M is not necessarily a subalgebra, and so we cannot assert that A = B + M.